# "repeat" query resend previous query

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm working on a french google assistant app using actions-on-google with "action sdk" and a PHP fulfillment API.

Since yesterday, when I say "répéter" ("repeat" in french), the request inputs[0].rawInputs[0].query doesn't contain "répéter", but the previous raw query.
For example, if in the previous request, I said "foo", when I say "repeat", the request contains "foo" instead of "repeat".

In addition, yesterday in the simulator, I said "good bye", and the response was "ciao amigo" without any request to the fulfillment (I don't use "ciao amigo" in my app).

Do anyone have this kind of "problem" ? It's a huge problem for me because my app is statefull, and if I said "continue" to progress in my step-by-step app, when I say "repeat", instead of repeating, it send "continue" and go forward to the next step.

Frederic

Comment: I've just said "pardon" ("excuse me" in french) which is another utterance for "repeat" intent in my app, and no request has been sent and the simulator said "pas de problème" (no problem) and quit !

Comment: I have the same problem! I had two ideas, the first one is that accents in input texts behaves strangely and doesn't trigger correctly. My second one was that maybe it became something built-in where saying "répéter" will repeat the last input. Anyway, I added in my intents "repeter" and when I test with written text I use that, I didn't try yet on my google home to see the behaviour

Comment: I tested it on my Google  Home and the "repeter" thing doesn't work (it was pretty obvious) so I added other keywords for my repeat intent ("quoi", "tu peux répéter") but yeah this is quite troublesome. I tested with "pardon" and it works for me (at least for now).

Comment: Today, request is sent correctly. Google may have fixed the bug :)